# Telethon check if user has privacy settings enabled

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telethon

I am using telethon to scrape members from a group, I can filter out active and non-active members but when adding members to another group I mostly get UserPrivacyRestrictedError.

because of that I usually get PeerFloodError after few request. is there a way to get participants that does not have privacy enabled?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can only find that out by trying to perform that action.